# Bukkit/Spigot - Projectile locations on hit detection completely wrong

Tags: vector, collision-detection, bukkit, projectile, aabb

I am making a custom 'gun' plugin for a minecraft server. My problem is that when attempting to detect where a projectile has landed, the locational difference between the projectile and the player being hit is too large to be detected by my headshot method. The only reason I am using a projectile trace for 'isHeadshot' is due to debugging trials.

This is my shoot method

```
public void shootGun(Player p) {
        if (getFirearmAction().isDelayed(p))
            return;

        double shiftYaw = (p.getLocation().getYaw() + 180) * (Math.PI/180);
        Vector shiftVec = new Vector(Math.cos(shiftYaw), 0.0D, Math.sin(shiftYaw)); //TODO: add bullet_spread


        for (int i = 0; i < projectileInfo.getAmount(); i++) {
            Projectile proj = (Projectile)p.getWorld().spawn(p.getEyeLocation().toVector().add(shiftVec.multiply(0.2D)).toLocation(p.getWorld()), getProjectileInfo().getProjectileClass());
            proj.setVelocity(UtilMethods.getBulletVelocity(p).multiply(projectileInfo.getSpeed()));
            proj.setShooter(p);
        }
        projectileInfo.playShootGunSound(p);
        getFirearmAction().performAction(p);
    }
```

This is the listener for a 'hit'

```
@EventHandler
    public void onEntDamage(EntityDamageByEntityEvent event) {
        if (event.getDamager() instanceof Projectile) {
            Projectile p = (Projectile)event.getDamager();
            if (p.getShooter() instanceof Player) {
                Player player = (Player)p.getShooter();
                Gun gun = UtilMethods.getGun(player);
                if (gun != null) {
                    int damage = gun.getProjectileInfo().getDamage();
                    if (event.getEntity() instanceof Player) {
                        Player ent = (Player)event.getEntity();

                        if (UtilMethods.isHeadShot(ent, p))
                            damage *= 2;
                    }
                    event.setDamage(damage);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

And finally, this is [isHeadshot, isInCuboid, and bulletVelocity] methods. The first two are substitute methods for trying to figure out a failed headshot detection... The getBulletVelocity method sets the correct velocity and direction of the projectile. (In this case I am working with Snowball.class)

```
public static boolean isHeadShot(Player victim, Projectile projectile) {

        Location locA = new Location(victim.getWorld(), victim.getEyeLocation().getX() -0.5, victim.getEyeLocation().getY() - 0.5, victim.getEyeLocation().getZ() - 0.5);
        Location locB = new Location(victim.getWorld(), victim.getEyeLocation().getX() +0.5, victim.getEyeLocation().getY() + 0.5, victim.getEyeLocation().getZ() + 0.5);

        for (double i = 0; i < 256; i+=0.8D) {
            System.out.println(projectile.getLocation() + " | " + victim.getLocation());
            projectile.getLocation().add(projectile.getVelocity().normalize().multiply(i));
            if (isInCuboid(locA, locB, projectile.getLocation())) {
                System.out.println(i);
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    public static boolean isInCuboid(Location min, Location max, Location varying) {
        double[] locs = new double[2];
        locs[0] = min.getX();
        locs[1] = max.getX();
        Arrays.sort(locs);
        if (varying.getX() > locs[1] || varying.getX() < locs[0])
            return false;
        locs[0] = min.getY();
        locs[1] = max.getY();
        Arrays.sort(locs);
        if (varying.getY() > locs[1] || varying.getY() < locs[0])
            return false;
        locs[0] = min.getZ();
        locs[1] = max.getZ();
        Arrays.sort(locs);
        if (varying.getZ() > locs[1] || varying.getZ() < locs[0])
            return false;
        return true;
    }

    public static Vector getBulletVelocity(Player shooter) {
        double yaw = Math.toRadians((-shooter.getLocation().getYaw() - 90.0f));
        double pitch = Math.toRadians(-shooter.getLocation().getPitch());

        double x = Math.cos(pitch) * Math.cos(yaw);
        double y = Math.sin(pitch);
        double z = -Math.sin(yaw) * Math.cos(pitch);

        Vector dirVec = new Vector(x, y, z).normalize();
        return dirVec;
    }
```

I would like some help since it seems that when the bullet causes damage, the bullet is already through the player's hitbox and can not be detected as a headshot anylonger. Any advice?

This is the locational difference. First location is projectile, second location is victim. However, for there to be a hit, the bullet must pass through the player at one point..

> [08:53:22] [Server thread/INFO]: Location{world=CraftWorld{name=San_Andreas},x=2501.8249706725665,y=73.62000000476837,z=1681.0750064188326,pitch=0.0,yaw=0.0} | Location{world=CraftWorld{name=San_Andreas},x=2508.7144181513295,y=72.0,z=1671.9424013003206,pitch=0.3,yaw=-8.100003}

Answer (score 0):

Listen for the [ProjectileHitEvent](https://hub.spigotmc.org/javadocs/spigot/org/bukkit/event/entity/ProjectileHitEvent.html) and check if the projectile's y-coord is within a certain distance of the y-coord of the hit player's eye location (the x and z coords are irrelevant for determining a headshot on a player).

Comment: I've actually registered a ProjectileHitEvent within this plugin for debugging purposes. The same problem occurs within the event. The Coords differ way too much. I do realize that x and z don't matter, however, it's still off putting, especially since I can no longer use bounding boxes properly.

Comment: `@EventHandler
    public void onProjectileHit(ProjectileHitEvent event) {
        if (event.getHitEntity() != null)
            System.out.println("PHE: " + event.getEntity().getLocation() + " | " + event.getHitEntity().getLocation());
    }`

I haven't done much in regards to the actual event. It fires after the EntityDamageEnt, which is where the damage modifier is set according to headshot/bodyshot.